# How do you use the Iterator class to remove duplicate elements from a List?

Tags: java, list, iterator

I am learning about the `Iterator` class and how to use it, and our teacher gives us a problem to use this class to loop through the whole `List`, find duplicates, and delete them. I have tried the following code:

```
void removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {

    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        if (list.contains(iterator.next())) {

            iterator.remove();

        }

    }

}
```

Of course, this code wouldn't work, because every element is in the `List` itself, so it would remove every single element in the List, making it empty. How would I fix this misconception (specifically the if conditional statement) so I will be able to make the `Iterator` delete all duplicate elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like direct operation on the original object, Maybe in a multi-threaded concurrent unsafe.

```
void removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {
    Set set = new HashSet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object element = iterator.next();
        if (!set.add(element)){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer perfectly answered my question. Thank you so much!